# My question is regrading handling of dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, dropdownbox

Here is the drop down .. In the dome there is no select tag to get all the options .. how to get those elements which are dynamic and also invisible in the dom ??[dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsDla.jpg)

In the dom there is n o select tag SO I would like to know How to handle such kind of Scenarios

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case select option would look like

```js
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://demoqa.com/select-menu");
driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("[id=withOptGroup]")).click();
WebElement menu = driver.findElement(new By.ByCssSelector("#selectMenuContainer [class*=-menu]"));
menu.findElement(new By.ById(constructOptionSelector("2", "0-1"))).click();
        
        
        ....
        
        
String constructOptionSelector(String groupIndex, String optionIndex) {
        return String.format("react-select-%s-option-%s", groupIndex, optionIndex);
    }
```

Where you have id builder that builds unique id value of each element
(react-select-2-option-0-0 , etc.)
Also possible to use general selector value like `[id*='react-select-']` and get option element by index or text.

And for sure this logic should be stored inside page driver.